# Registering to appear in "media picks" new feature in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

For the past year Google has been deploying a new feature for Android Auto, where the system can present the user with a list of suggestions compiled from different media apps installed on his device (Such as Spotify, Youtube Music, etc)

I have a Media app designed for Android Auto as well, and since this feature has started to be more common I want to add support for this new feature so tracks from my app will also appear in the "media picks" list.
Searching for documentation or information about this feature has yield no results for me

Does anyone have any information about this topic? Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286685/include-our-application-in-default-popup-to-launch-the-media?rq=4